# Windows API, Media Pause virtual key doesnt work

Tags: c++, windows, windows-11

I have this following code, and although it works when `arg = 2` or `arg = 3`, it seems to have no effect when `arg = 1`. I really cannot see anything wrong I did. It started to not work after I switched to Windows 11. Any help is appreicated.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{
    //int arg = argv[1][0] - 48;
    int arg = 1;

    KEYBDINPUT kbi;
    kbi.wScan = 0;
    kbi.dwFlags = 0; 
    kbi.time = 0;
    kbi.dwExtraInfo = (ULONG_PTR)GetMessageExtraInfo();

    switch (arg)
    {
    case 1:
        kbi.wVk = VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE; // PAUSE
        break;
    case 2:
        kbi.wVk = VK_VOLUME_UP; // VOLUP
        break;
    case 3:
        kbi.wVk = VK_VOLUME_DOWN; // VOLDOWN
        break;
    case 4:
        kbi.wVk = VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK; // FORWARD
        break;
    case 5:
        kbi.wVk = VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK; // BACKWARD
        break;
    default:
        return 2;
    }

    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki = kbi;

    input.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    auto x = SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    x = SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `INPUT input = { 0 };` to initialize.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani nop, didn't work either. I'm wondering whether Windows API in W11 has changed or not?

Comment: Does `VK_VOLUME_UP/DOWN` work? I don't have Windows 11, maybe it's just not configured to work with some application.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani yes, those are the only ones working. NEXT_TRACK or PREVIOUS_TRACK doesn't work either. Well I am running spotify, and when I click Fn+F4, which is the real media pause key, music actually pauses. So I don't know whether it is realted to the application or not but it doesn't seem so.